Does $\sum{a_n}=+\infty$ means $\lim\sum{a_nx^n}=+\infty$?
Suppose $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}$ is a power serie and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.
If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}=+\infty$, can we claim that $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}=+\infty$ ?
If we have the condition that $a_n\geq{0}$, I can prove that it is right.
$\forall{M>0}$, suppose that $m$ is a whole number satisfies $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}a_n\geq{M}$. Then, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $x$ belongs to $(1-\delta,1)$, we have that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\geq{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}a_nx^n}>\frac{M}{2}$. Hence, we obtain that$\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}=+\infty$.
But is this proposition still correct when we know nothing about $a_n$ ? Otherwise, is there any counter example ?

Let $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$. Given $x \in (0, 1)$ and $N, M \in \mathbb{N}$ with $N < M$, due to the Abel transformation we have
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^M a_n x^n = -s_N x^N + \sum_{n=N}^{M-1} s_n \big( x^n - x^{n+1} \big) + s_M x^M.$$
From $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 1$ it is easy to get $s_M x^M \xrightarrow{M \to \infty} 0$, hence
$$\tag{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n -s_N x^N + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} s_n \big( x^n - x^{n+1} \big).$$
Given $A > 0$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n \geqslant A$ form $n \geqslant N$. Then
$$\tag{2} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} s_n \big( x^n - x^{n+1} \big) \geqslant A \cdot \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \big( x^n - x^{n+1} \big) = A \cdot x^N$$
and
$$\tag{3} \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n -s_N x^N = s_N - s_N = 0.$$
From $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, when $x$ is sufficiently close to $1^-$ we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_n \big( x^n - x^{n+1} \big) \geqslant A-1,$$
which proves that
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \infty.$$
